# Kivy hello world script yields black screen on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, kivy

On running the basic hello world script found here  - https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html the following log is generated and a windows pops up completely blank and black.

I've installed Kivy 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7
I have also tried upgrading my graphics driver but this did not solve the issue.

Log:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /home/minzey/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-22_7.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] OSC: using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO              ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 10.1.0>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell >
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO              ] GL: Shading version <1.30>
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max size <8192>
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max units <32>
[INFO              ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO              ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO              ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
```

Here is the code :

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Post the code on pastebin or something.

Comment: Did you do the `return Label(text='Hello World')` in `build()`?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I've updated my question.

Comment: Ah-ha! The indentation of `def build(self)` is not proper. And Python is *real* serious about indentation.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `xclip` using `sudo apt-get install xclip`.
Also, check your `gtk` version. Update it to `gtk3`.

Edit: install ffmpeg also.

Comment: xclip is already installed on my system and i have both gtk2 and gtk3.